# ajax кроссдоменный запрос. Не могу получить данные

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

Возникла проблема при получении запроса ajax типа jsonp.

У меня есть некий .json на сервере, мне по нажатию кнопки надо его получить и записать в localStorage.

Но чтобы проверить что я его получил хотел вывести в консоль, при нажатии кнопки в браузере видно что запрос состоялся, а в консоли получаю ошибку.

Я так понял не удается конвертировать json в jsObject.

jQuery 1.11.1 (использую для совместимости jQuery mobile)

код скрипта:

function myRequest(){

```
        $.ajaxSetup();                      
        $.ajax({
                    url:"http://example.net/result.json",
                    dataType:'jsonp',
                    contentType:"application/json, charset=utf-8",
                    crossDomain:true,

                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        console.log(xhr.status);
                        console.log(thrownError);
                      },

                    success:function(data){console.log(data);}



                    });                 
        }
```

$(document).on( "pageinit","#main", function(){

```
    $('#btnDownload').click(function( event ){
        myRequest();
        //myFunction();


    }); 
});
```

Скрин консоли:
[image: Ошибка в консоле]

Comment: ты уверен, что сервер поддерживает запрос jsonp?

Comment: А в консоли никаких ошибок не падает? Данные не выводятся в success? А добавьте еще `error:function(data){console.log(data);}`

Comment: @Deniss Bubnov 
Добавил обработчик "error: function(data){console.log(data)}," перед success
И получил такой [ответ](http://imgur.com/3BHgA4k) в консоль.

Все равно не понимаю в чем проблема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все было на много проще, так как я тупенький, я не знал что нужен еще серверный скрипт для jsonp запросов:

```
$callback = (isset($_GET['callback']) ? $_GET['callback'] : null);
if (isset($callback))
    echo $callback . '([JSON HERE])';
else
    echo '[JSON HERE]';
```

в ajax запросе обращаться  не к  .json файлу а к .php (или какой у вас язык на сервере).

```
$.ajax({
                    url:"http://example.net/json-generator.php",
                    dataType:'jsonp',

                    crossDomain:true,

                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        console.log(xhr.status);
                        console.log(thrownError);
                      },

                    success:function(data){console.log(data);}



                    });                 
        }
```

Вот детальное [описание](https://web.archive.org/web/20160114013014/http://json-jsonp-tutorial.craic.com/index.html) отличий json и jsonp

Answer (score 1):

Для кроссдоменного AJAX-запроса необходимо чтобы сервер возвращал заголовок:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Вернее для получения данных с сервера, отправлять то вы что угодно можете. CORS браузерная технология.

Comment: Но jsonp может обходить CORS. Или этот метод уже не  актуален?

Comment: @LischukAndry Да, сорри, не обратил внимания.

Answer (score -1):

Можно:

Есть небольшой трюк с PHP. И этот трюк будет работать не только с Google, но и с любыми сайтами, к которым у вас нет доступа и вы не можете добавить Access-Control-Allow-Origin *

Нам нужно создать PHP-файл (например. getContentFromUrl.php) на нашем сервере и сделать обращение к нему.

**PHP**

```
<?php

$ext_url = $_POST['ext_url'];

echo file_get_contents($ext_url);

?>
```

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'getContentFromUrl.php', // link to your PHP file
    data: {
        // url куда наш сервер будет отправлять запрос, который мы не можем сделать через AJAX
        'ext_url': 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114436/access-control-allow-origin-error-sending-a-jquery-post-to-google-apis'
    },
    success: function(data) {
        // теперь мы можем взять любые данные из внешнего url, потому что у нас есть вся страница
        var $h1 = $(data).find('h1').html();

        $('h1').text($h1);
    },
    error:function() {
        console.log('Error');
    }
});
```

**Как это работает:**

1. Ваш браузер с помощью JS отправит запрос на ваш сервер
2. Ваш сервер отправит запрос на любой другой сервер и получит ответ
3. Ваш сервер отправит этот ответ в ваш JS файл

И мы можем добавить event типа onClick на кнопку. Надеюсь, это поможет!